# How can Forms.WebBrowser use a plugin which works in IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry, webbrowser-control

I have a Forms.WebBrowser which I use to navigate to a bank's login page. The users enter their credentials and log in. The problematic case concerns logging in with a third party Minikey which is a plug-in (shows in Manage add-ons in internet explorer). It doesn't work with the WebBrowser (instead, there is an error message from the web page, same as when the plug in isn't installed). On IE this login works fine.
I already tried the following:

- I set some registry values: FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN and FEATURE_SECURITYBAND, etc. -
  with the latter the webbrowser should have shown the security band where the user could choose to run the plugin, but it did not work on every computer.
- I reset the IE options
- I Set Zone mapping by using the IInternetZoneManager interface.

Any solution enabling the login would help.
I would add that the problem appeared on Windows 7.1 and 8.1 64 bit machines.
I haven't found any topics relevant to my problem.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Who'd use an non-mainstream browser to access their bank account? Sounds a little odd to me.

Comment: Actually many users do since this module automates their bank pages import.